# How to create a virtual video CD/DVD

Tags: dvd-burning, cd-burning

Let's say I have a video file in `AVI` or `MPEG` format.

I want to make a video CD (or DVD) for that video file (not data CD/DVD). But I don't want to burn a real CD -- I want to make a virtual video CD, so that I have as a result an `iso` file (which when I burn to a real CD gives me the actual video CD.)

How can I do this?

I have PowerISO as my virtual CD software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the tutorial link, same for video cds too.

http://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/iso-maker.htm

Edited:

You can use CDburnerXP. Its best free and light Burner. 
Go to home page for downloading the file.
http://www.cdburnerxp.se/help/Data/compiledata

Comment: I remember Windows' `Movie Maker` can create video file and burn ISO. Have you tried?

Comment: This also works for video files or any files compressed to iso format.

Answer (score 1):

I just googled for DVD Authoring Software and found this: [DVDStyler](http://www.dvdstyler.org/en/) which perhaps will do what you need (authoring a DVD, and create an ISO).

I checked their PDF documentation, once you create your DVD (with the menu option etc if you want to), it will create an ISO file. Which then you can burn to any physical DVD after that.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use Nero Burning ROM 12 and select the virtual image as the output writer.